# How to convert a string to char array then return the array to another class?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, return

I need the program to accept the user string then output each character of the string on a seperate line.

This is the method in my Main class that executes the menu. Case 6 is the one I am trying to get to work.

```
  private static void executeMenuChoice(int menuChoice, StringManipulator myManipulator)
{
    switch (menuChoice)
    {
        case 1:
            String userUpperCase = myManipulator.listUppercase();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your string value converted to uppercase is: " + userUpperCase);
            break;
        case 2:
            String listVowels = myManipulator.listVowels();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Here are the vowels in your string: " + listVowels);
            break;
        case 3:
            String replaceVowels = myManipulator.replaceVowels();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Here is your string with values replaced by underscores: " + replaceVowels);
            break;
        case 4:
            int countVowels = myManipulator.countVowels();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Here is the number of vowels in your string: " + countVowels);
            break;
        case 5:
            String reverseString = myManipulator.reverseString();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Here is your string in reverse: " + reverseString);
            break;
        case 6:
            char[] character = myManipulator.newlineString();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Here is your string with each character on a separate line: " + character);
            break;
        case 7:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are now exiting the program.");
            break;
    }
```

This is the method in my second class to convert user string to a char array to output each character of the string on a different line.

```
        public char[] newlineString() {

    String newLine = getUserString();

    char[] chars = newLine.toCharArray();

    return chars;
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(String.join(System.lineSeparator(), "abc".split("")));`

Comment: It took me several passes to work out what you were asking.

Comment: After the user inputs a string value and selects option 6 on the menu "Print each character of string value on a seperate line." I need the public char[] newlineString() method to take the userString and take the characters and output them on seperate lines. Then return it to the main class for output to the user.

Comment: Since we seem to be failing to communicate: try this, `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.join(System.lineSeparator(), "Zayne".split("")));`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're trying to concatenate an array to a text string.

try like this:

```
case 6:
        char[] character = myManipulator.newlineString();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
               "Here is your string with each character on a separate line: " +
                String.join("\n", character));
        break;
```